# Can't start my pc Pop OS 20.04

Tags: startup, pop-os

I have an Ubuntu's distro, Pop OS, and I have a problem. I restarted my pc and then it doesn't start anymore(I couldn't restarted also). When I start my pc it appears the encryption password and after that it says "cryptsetup: cryptdata set up successfully" and then it should go to the login screen but it stays on a black page, like if it were stuck. I don't know what can I do, so any help it will be appreciate it. I can access to the root terminal. I don't know if having the disk encrypted is a bad thing for this problem, but I was thinking in removing it. Is it possible doing it from root terminal?

Anyways, if anyone have any suggestion for starting my pc again I am all ears.

PD: I don't update my OS since 1 or 2 weeks ago.

PD2: I am newbie on Linux and this site.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1(based on gecko's answer):

1- If I press ESC I can start from GRUB, and I can choose recovery mode.

[image: recoverymodelinux]

2- In the recovery mode I can access to the root terminal. I access to the recovery mode pressing ESC on the startup or CTRL + ALT + F5.

3- I don't know how to restore the system from a backup(I was thinking in format it and install Ubuntu).

4- I don't know how to analise logs files.

5- I don't think it has happen any update on the background. The only thing that I know is that I was trying to start Microsoft Teams program, but it didn't start(before my pc crashed). So I decided to restart the pc and it didn't start anymore.

Comment: Since the image is just text, please transcribe the image to a text block--not all our users can see images. Some are simply visually impaired, while others are stuck using primitive text-only methods to access the site because their main system is down and they are desperately seeking help to get it back up. You can get help on the site's Markdown code to help in formatting the text-only block to resemble the way it looks on screen.

Comment: When you say it goes to an encryption password, does this mean it asks for your decryption password, and you enter it (correctly) before it proceeds to the next part? What about the blank screen? Is it completely blank, or is there a flashing underscore cursor in the upper left corner? Are you trying to log in to a GUI or TUI (text-only, like "Login:")? While at the blank screen, can you switch to another virtual console (Press and hold CTRL+ALT, then press F2 for console 2, F3 for console 3, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I welcome you to the *nix universe, your question unfortunately does not help with troubleshooting a lot, since what you explained can originate from many causes. You can:

1. Try pressing the ESC button during boot to switch from the graphical boot screen to a more verbose text output
2. You say you can access a terminal after stating you are faced with a blank screen. Explain how you managed to open a visible terminal, if your screen is blank.
3. Restore the system from a backup.
4. Use a live boot media to attempt accessing the partition and analyze log files (seeing your root partition is encrypted, this is more advanced, as you would need to utilize cryptsetup to mount the partition from the live media).
5. Ask yourself if you performed any recent modifications, software installations or configuration changes. You state not having performed any recent updates - did no updates run automatically in the background either?

Comment: I have edited @gecko

Comment: @gecko: Please do not create an answer to ask for more detail instead of actually answering. You can post comments (even multiple comments) to ask for further details. As i is, someone might have the same issue, see this post, and hopefully check it out hoping to find an answer/solution... and become confused and frustrated when they find out here is no answer, just more questions.